# What in the forest is suitable as a foundation to primitive structures such as log cabins, in northeast USA?

Tags: diy, shelter, primitive-tools

Cedar is a great example of a log that makes a good log cabin foundation. Solid and naturally rot resistant. Are there other species' logs suitable as foundations in northeast USA? Rocks can also be stacked though that is a much more permanent build than many primitive structures. What other logs or natural materials work well for primitive log cabin foundations?

By foundation I mean whatever connects the main structure with the ground and is contact with the ground surface. There's all kinds of different primitive structures, so maybe a rot resistant log is not always needed. For example, vertical log cabins might not need logs laying flat on the ground if I understand it correctly, and instead are supported with pillars (charred logs) buried in the ground with other logs nailed, lashed, or somehow joined to serve as the horizontal frame above the ground.

As an example, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7xqy4OXzhc) shows a structure being build with both horizontal logs on the ground and standing posts to support the rest of the building. In this video it's mostly built with cedar, but could something like that be done with other logs common in areas like the Adirondacks? Red spruce, eastern hemlock, white pine, red pine, balsam fir, birches, maples, and more.

Answer (score 2):

Black locust is in some areas of the northeast now, but I don't know about the 
Adirondacks. It is listed as very durable for rot resistance, and is mentioned as being used for fence posts because of this.

[Other durable species can be found from this link](https://www.wood-database.com/wood-finder/?fwp_location=north-america&fwp_decay=very-durable). There are 31 listed as very durable (greater than 25 years of service life in ground contact, but only for the heartwood) in North America. You can check for each in your area. Black Cherry is one listed that should be in your area. Sassafras is considered very durable, but it's relatively rare to see sizes large enough for a cabin foundation. White Oak and some other oaks, and a few species of cedar are the others I see listed that might be in your area. Black Walnut is listed, but it also mentions that it is susceptible to insect attack.